# Mount volume into Docker container and see changes on host system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like changes made within a container to be visible on the host system. How do I do that?

This is the docker-compose.yml I am using right now:

```
version: '3'
services:
  timfoto:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "bundle exec middleman s"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "4567:4567"
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
ADD Gemfile .
ADD Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle
VOLUME ["/myapp"]
WORKDIR myapp
EXPOSE 4567
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have what's required to share files and file-changes between the host and container. What is written in the /myapp directory inside container should be visible outside of the container, on the host.

For this to function, you need to make sure:

- On Windows you must share the host-folder in the Docker For Windows Settings
- At times relative paths have given me headaches when specifying the host-part of the volume directive. Consider using absolute paths here.

Comment: I was looking for changes via git in a folder that was ignored… . Dumbest thing I did for a while :)